# Send broadcast intent from service to Application Class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, service, broadcast

Is it possible to send an intent from a service to an Application class? Not Activity?

I wouldn't know what activity would be running at a particular time, so I am adding a boolean flag in the activity class that detects the activity and sends the appropriate data based on the broadcast received.

Comment: Why application class? Can you clarify your scenario

Comment: @VivekMishra I have a service running that does XMPP heavy lifting. This service runs in the background forever. Now when I want to transfer data from the service to the app, the user might be using the app or not. So I want to first wake up the app, then send the intent and the application class processes it to the right activity

Comment: why application class? that can be done in broadcast receiver too

Comment: @VivekMishra how?

Comment: Simply calling the intent for the activity that you want to open

Comment: @VivekMishra means that if the user was already on that activity and doing something, the activity would get recreated, all previous work lost

Comment: well to understand that you have to first read about `launchMode` flags for an activity and save/Restore instance state.

Comment: OP any update? Does the answer below satisfies you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Service` is active, then your `Application` class is *active* as well.

Otherwise you wouldn't be able to use `getApplicationContext()`.

Although I'm skeptic about **a service that runs forever** there is a very clean way to make the `Service` communicate with a certain `Activity`, should the last one be currently active.

Such clean way is called [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html).

The `Activity` meant to receive the data should register a `BroadcastReceiver` in `onResume()` and unregister it in `onPause()`.

You instantiate your `BroadcastReceiver` in your Activity's `onCreate()`

```
this.localBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Do what you have to do here if you receive data from the Service.
    }
}
```

You create a Filter so your Activity only listens to a certain type of signals.

```
private IntentFilter notifIntentFilter new IntentFilter("com.you.yourapp.MY_SIGNAL");
```

in `onResume()`

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(this.localBroadcastReceiver, notifIntentFilter);
```

in `onPause()`

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(this.localBroadcastReceiver);
```

Now whenever you want to send data to your Activity, your Service can call:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.you.yourapp.MY_SIGNAL");
// put your data in intent

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

If your `Activity` is *awake*, it will respond to the signal. Otherwise, if it's in the background, or it is not instantiated it won't.

You can apply this pattern to as many Activities as you wish.

---

Still, **I have never used** this inside the `Application` class. But you can try to register your receiver there. It might work, since if the `Application` class is destroyed, the `BroadcastReceiver` is destroyed too and thus probably unregistered as well.

The point is, if your Application gets destroyed, your Service will be killed as well. Unless you launched it in another process. But then it will have it's own instance of `Application`; and this is a complex thing you probably do not want to get into details now...

---

**Important**: since the `Application` class is not tied to any UI component, you can do whatever you need directly inside your service. If you need to manipulate the UI, then the pattern described above will work for you.

Please read about new [Android's background limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html).

---

**Edit:**

Oh yeah right, if you need your Service to call a function declared in your `Application` class, you can just do

```
((MyApplication) getApplication()).myFunctionToHandleData(Intent intent);
```

---

I didn't really understand your question though, but either of the methods described above should work for you.

Comment: Tried this and it didn't quite work. The calling class is in a separate module.

Comment: @bezaleel what do you mean in another module? If you posted a little code it would help us find you a solution

Comment: Figured this out, the above answer does work. I just extend the class from the separate module/library into the current one and then used a broadcast receiver. I couldn't however send an intent to the Application class itself instead of first to an activity but this works.