# Determine if any of the activities are visible or not (app in background)

Tags: android

Is there a way to determine if any of the activities are visible or not (the situation when the app is in the background). I'm trying to implement un-logging mechanism without sessions and I did handle the situations when the screen is off / locked, timeout, pressing the home button, but when another app is being launched and putting my app in the background, well there's the problem.

Or a way to check if an activity is being paused because there's an intent were called to open a new activity. This way, say I have three activities `A`, `B`, `C` and currently `B` is opened. So,

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
  if (startActivityCalled) {
    // it continues to activity `C` or any else for that matter
  } else {
    // if screen were locked, for example
    // it goes to the activity `A` and finishes the current activity
  }
}
```

Comment: [Use `ProcessLifecycleOwner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner.html) from the Architecture Components.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if an Android application is running in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/checking-if-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-background)

Answer (score 0):

Well, when your application goes into the background, the function `onPause()` of your current `Activity` is called.

You can easily override it and place your logic there

```
@Override 
protected void onPause() {
    // Another Activity has started, user has closed the application 
    // or started another one...
}
```

When your `Activity` comes into the foreground again, then `onResume()` is triggered.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
     // the user re-opened your application, or came back from
     // another activity
}
```

Note that `onResume()` is also **always** called after `onCreate()`.

**EDIT:**

If I understood correctly all you need to know it's if there is a visible `Activity`. Not which one...

In that case @Journey's answer below **should suit your needs.**

---

I was wondering though, from where your will be checking if your Actvities are visible or not. I guess you will be using a `Service` or some sort of background mechanism.

In that case, a pattern commonly used pattern is the [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html).

I had written a related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46604841/8524301) though you can find many others on SO.

Basically, in each of your activities, you register a `Receiver` when your `Activity` is visible, and un-register it when it goes into the background.

From your `Service` you send an `Intent`, and the `Activity` that is visible, if any, will respond to it.

Create the `Receiver` in your Activities.

```
this.localBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Do what you have to do here if you receive data from the Service / Background Task
    }
}
```

Set up a `Filter` that will distinguish your signal from others:

```
public static final IntentFilter SIGNAL_FILTER = new IntentFilter("com.you.yourapp.MY_SIGNAL");
```

Remember to register the `Receiver` every time any of your `Activities` is visible.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // Listen if a Service send me some data 
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(this.localBroadcastReceiver, SIGNAL_FILTER);
}
```

When the `Activity` is closed stop listening to the signal:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // I'm going to the background, no need to listen to anything anymore...
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(this.localBroadcastReceiver);
}
```

When your `Service`, or Background Task wants to send data to the currently visible `Activity`, you can call

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(SomeActivity.SIGNAL_FILTER);
// put your data in intent
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

If an Activity is visible it will receive the Intent, otherwise nothing will happen.

Comment: The activities (plural). Otherwise, it would trigger every time the activity is changed. And thanks for the lifecycle reference, though I well aware of it.

Comment: @Katherine is that what you were looking for? Otherwise could you explain your question better

Comment: What if activities are from library and you are not aware how much activities there are and when will be displayed?

Comment: hey @raV720 I answered this question 5 years ago and I never worked with Android again. I think you are better off by posting a new question on SO

Answer (score 0):

try to check isDestroyed() before doing any operation if the activity is in the background.