# Communicate between service and activity

Tags: java, android

I have a class in a service

```
MyClass m = new MyClass();
```

and inside my class I check if I have permission to overlay the view; if so, it's ok, otherwise I must start an activity

```
if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(mContext)) {
    // draw over app
} else {
    // start the activity
    Intent i  = new Intent(context,Calls.class);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

When I start the activity I have a problem communicating between the class and the activity. I know how to use the interface but how can I register it in activity.

Some time I want to pass an object or data from the class to the activity or from the activity to the class... how can I do that?

I saw many examples in Stack Overflow about how to communicate between service and activity; they suggest to start the class from the activity but **this does not work** in my app because my class must be running all the time.

Comment: what do u want to do in your activity?

Comment: @Joe i have surfaceView so i will send mediaStream from my class to activity and display it in activity ... also some event like click on button

Comment: why can't you create instance of that class  in your activity ?

Comment: @Joe if activity paused i will lose the call between two user .. the class make the call so the activity only for display time and video so if activity paused call will continue

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use an event bus like mechanism where you can send or receive events through out your app, Though there are several libraries out there, I would recommend using [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) library for android.

Usage is pretty simple just register in your activity `onCreate`

```
Bus bus = new Bus();
bus.register(this);
```

For sending events

```
// example data to post
public class TestData {
    public String message;
}

// post this data
bus.post(new TestData().message="Hello from the activity");
```

And subscribe to events like this

```
@Subscribe public void getMessage(TestData data)  {
    // TODO: React to the event somehow!
}
```

More info [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-EventBusOtto/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement a communication pattern between a `Service` and an `Activity`, you should use a [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html).

It will turn handy because, in case your `Service` is still on but your `Activity`
has been destroyed (very common situation), then the 'messagging' between the two will simply have no effect (no `NPE` or whatsoever will be thrown).

**Step 1**

Create a `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Activity` and define an `ID` / `Filter`

```
this.localBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Do what you have to do here if you receive data from the Service / Background Task
    }
}

public static final IntentFilter SIGNAL_FILTER = new IntentFilter("com.you.yourapp.MY_SIGNAL")
```

**Step 2**

In your `Activity` register the broadcast in `onResume()` and unregister it in `onPause()`.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // Listen if a Service send me some data
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(this.localBroadcastReceiver, SIGNAL_FILTER);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // I'm going to the background / or being destroyed: no need to listen to anything anymore...
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(this.localBroadcastReceiver);
}
```

Your `Activity` is now ready to receive data from any other component in your `Application`.

If it's in the background, then there is no need to update the `UI`: in fact the `Activity` will not respond if in the background.

In the same way, if it's being garbage collected, the `Receiver` will be unregistered and the `Activity` will just not respond to anything.

If the `Activity` is resumed / restarted, `onResume()` will be triggered and the `Receiver` will be registered again.

**Step 3**

All you need to do right now, is send data from the `Service`.

Simply call

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(SomeActivity.SIGNAL_FILTER);
// put your data in intent
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and your `Activity` will accordingly respond to the signal.

---

It's surprising how few people know about the `LocalBroadcastManager` and instead use some self-implemented callback / singleton pattern, which increases complexity and non-readability.

This pattern is built-in in `Android`, so you don't need external libraries. As for security, this ensures that your signals stay internal to your application: no data can therefore be read by other apps.

I similarly answered to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46604002/send-broadcast-intent-from-service-to-application-class/46604841#46604841).